# Who do we want as moderators?

Tags: discussion, moderation

As one of  The 7 Essential Meta Questions of Every Beta, I figured I post it out here.

Please feel free to post nominations.

Comment: I think its too early at the moment, we should wait a week at least. After that we should post our nominations.

Comment: There's no problem opening this now, I'd like to get folks in place as soon as there's enough activity to look at. Looking at the following this saw on Area 51, it'll not be long after we switch to public beta before we're ready to get the pro-tems in place.

Comment: **Looking at the following this saw on Area 51**, huh ?? @TimPost

Comment: @Skippy I'm just expecting a rather good turnout in participation, this site has more than a few of our known prolific contributors in the list of users that committed. Just meaning, it's not going to be long before there's enough participation for us to make a decision.

Comment: @TimPost agreed with you but for becoming moderator we should know how he/she is going to act with this power. Which can be judge by seeing his activities like his edits, comments and reputation etc which is too soon to see at this moment.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - that's what I just said (or was implying).

Comment: The Stack Exchange community managers pick 3 pro-tems when in public beta; until the site graduates, the community doesn't get (much of) a vote. :-) But you can count on the community managers recognizing moderator material when they see it.

Comment: @AnkitSharma - I would guess that many of the more prolific posters on this site will also be on other sites and may very likely already be moderators as a result. That might give you some idea of how they might behave.

Comment: I agree. Just because a person is very active in a seven day period doesn't make them a good moderator. I prefer mods that are moderately active on the specific site but active on other parts of the network, this makes them much more reliable than people who are only active on one site.

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing nominations of *other* people here, not just self-nominations.  (Don't worry; you don't have to take the job if you don't want.)  Whom do we as a community notice demonstrating the qualities of a good moderator?

Comment: @MonicaCellio i have stated this trend and nominated Skippy in the thoughts that he can be a good pre temp mod. And can get good response.

Comment: @MonicaCellio unfortunately i can't upvote a non-self nomination myself.

Comment: Someone should edit in the theory of moderation link...

Comment: We want someone who is kind to newcomers.  They should go in the chat room and see if people are asking for help.  They should avoid publicly shaming members.

Comment: @AnkitSharma, I assume that whoever posts a nomination supports it, so whether it's a self-nomination or a nomination of someone else, the poster's inability to vote on that answer is a wash.

Answer (score 18):

I am more that willing to act as a moderator! :) I used to be a moderator on Libraries.SE before the site was unfortunately closed, and I have a lot of experience with the network (I have 17k rep on Arqade, for example). Stack Exchange is one of my passions, and I love seeing sites grow and helping them become super awesome and full of good quality content with an involved community who is excited to participate and also guide new users.

I am super passionate about pets (I only have a cat at the moment, but have had a myriad of other animals in my life, and grew up in a rural area and have experience with many animals in that environment as well), and I have a love of research and finding information, which I think is also a good fit for a site like this.

I love seeing how active and excited we are so far, and it's only been a couple of days (well, one in my world, but the SE day runs different in my time zone!). I would love to be involved in helping this site grow and be another awesome part of the Stack Exchange network.

This site is full of super cool people who also seem incredibly smart and excited for where we are going to head as a site, and I think that no matter who we end up with as moderators, this site will be amazing.

Comment: It would be great to see you back in the moderator corps!

Comment: A pleasant person _(from what I see in chat)_ ;) and you seem to know your way around SE well enough.

Comment: +1 Ashley you have all my support. I've only chatted for a short while with you in the main chat room but I've seen your enthusiasm for this website and preference for quality that should be rewarded on its own. You have that _panache_ (in the positive sense) of a leader, but also a healthy sense of humor that is often required to deal with the additional stress that comes with the position. I have no doubt we'll soon chat in Teachers' Lounge. Godspeed!

Comment: Ashley has a good record of participation, particularly on meta and in chat, and comes across as kind, knowledgable in the ways of SE, and dedicated.

Comment: All of these nice comments are making me feel all warm and fuzzy inside. This is a great community! <3

Answer (score 9):

I'm with Ashley on this, when it comes to that. I'm an active moderator on [Photo.SE](https://photo.stackexchange.com/) and have had a lot of experience in helping keep the site moving (usually by not jumping in, but sometimes you have to) and know what I'd be getting myself into as a consequence. I'm also a huge animal lover and I've had dogs, cats, fish, turtles, hamsters, guinea pigs, rabbits, and birds in my life.

At any rate, I latched onto this site in Area 51 because this looked like a site that really could be something that so many people would find help in and one that I would enjoy actively participating in as much as Photography. So far, so fun. :)

Comment: I think John would make a good moderator.  His activity on the site so far has been thoughtful and wise, particularly in meta discussions, and he has relevant outside experience.

Answer (score 9):

After considerable thought I have decided to volunteer to be considered for [Moderator Pro Tempore](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/07/moderator-pro-tempore/).  This is not a decision that I have undertaken lightly. The Moderator Pro Tempore has duties beyond those of a [moderator of a site after beta](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators).  I am lacking in some the extra attributes.  For the record my real name is James Jenkins.

- I am naturally an introvert, and don't spend a lot of time in chat, and socializing across sites.
- I have a full time employment and volunteer with two local animal organizations (see my profile) limiting my available time online.
- I am relatively new in the stack exchange family.

I do bring several attributes that tend to make me a good candidate for moderator.

- My full time job is on the computer, and due to my natural introvert tendencies break time is online and this give time to address housekeeping tasks.
- This is not my first beta, I was fairly active in birthing [Space](https://space.stackexchange.com/), which is maturing nicely :)
- I believe that moderators should use their tools, as stewards of the site, not to give extra weight to personal opinion.
- I have a long history of online community activity and housekeeping. I have several years of experience in the Wikimedia/Wikipedia family, where I have edited under a alias since 2006.  As there is no reliable way to confirm cross site identity, [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/41296/were-there-hints-in-cards-shadow-series-that-enders-parents-genetically-enhanc/41305#41305) should provided sufficient clues for you to reach your own conclusion on that identity and the likelihood of the claim.
- My activities as an admin on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org) and [Wikisource](https://en.wikisource.org/) have focused mostly around vandalism, copyright, and general housekeeping tasks.

In summary, while I don't have some of the site promotion attributes that are desirable for the position, I do have the attributes to address the long term, mundane housekeeping tasks (i.e. [OCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OCD)), and I understand what that entails.

As a pet parent, we have 3 rabbits who are very active in our life, including tagging along on camping trips.

Comment: +1 and from past experience, I'm most confident you'd make any mod team stronger. A lot of what you describe as your _weaknesses_ shouldn't concern anyone, because all the tasks when that would matter should be a community effort, not merely of a few select individuals. You might need to have some chats open tho, even if you don't plan on being the most talkative one there. ;) All the best!

Comment: Disclosure, while I don't know Tildal Wave personally I did nominate for moderator on [Space](http://space.stackexchange.com/users/49/tildalwave), so any support here might be considered retaliation :)  As that posting is no longer public (or at least I can't find it), it is important to disclose.

Answer (score 7):

I'll volunteer too.

I'm active on multiple SE sites, and have been the moderator *pro tem* on [parenting.se](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/) for more than 2 years now.

I'm big on using meta as a tool for policy and scope definition (just ask the people on scifi.se!), and I'm very familiar with the beta site process here, along with many of the growing pains and pitfalls that a site can encounter.

As for my interest in pets, specifically...  I have had pets consistently for my entire life, including: cats, dogs, fish, frogs, hermit crabs, ferrets, snakes, lizards, a scorpion, mice, and a rat.  I worked for a while in an animal hospital (at the kennel, although I assisted the veterinarians with both client visits and medical treatments, on occasion).  I currently have 4 pet cats and one pet human (age 3).

I love animals, and am passionate not only about their role as friends and companions, but also in ensuring that we act responsibly towards pet ownership.

I was very excited to watch this proposal progress through area51, and I'm genuinely impressed with the progress and participation I've seen here in the short time since private beta started!  We've got the start of a great community here, with a lot of great people.

Answer (score 4):

I would like to nominate [**Monica Cellio**](https://pets.stackexchange.com/users/31/monica-cellio); if she would like to take the role. Being an extraordinarily experienced user on SE, she has moderation experience on SE  on [Mi Yodeya](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/472/monica-cellio).

Monica is an intelligent, insightful contributor; always calm and polite and has been an active participant on the site. I think she is a great asset to our site.

Monica is currently positioned as the second most active user on [Meta here](https://pets.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=participation).

Comment: +1 for rational answers.  Tagging this comment with @MonicaCellio so this post is noticed by her.

Comment: Thanks for the kind words.  I'm an elected mod on Mi Yodeya, a pro-tem on Writers, and a 10K user on Workplace and EL&U, so I've got a fair bit of experience with SE, moderation, and subjective questions.  We have several fine candidates here, so while I'd accept if offered, I'm not pushing myself either.  "Active, senior user" is a pretty good role to strive for, too. :-)  (I do admit to some curiosity about the downvotes on this nomination, as I'm not aware of things I've done to bother people -- if I've given offense or something, I'd sure like to know that!)

Comment: I think Monica would be a great mod.

Answer (score 2):

I think this site has a huge potential, and as such, I'd like to nominate myself.

3 days late to join the party, I already see the kinds of questions around here and what this site is capable of becoming.

I'm a moderator on [another site](http://anime.stackexchange.com) and as such I am familiar with

- Moderator tools
- Moderator policy
- Stack Exchange policy
- Dealing with users from a mod perspective

I love pets and animals in general, currently have one dog, with previous assorted array of pets (including dogs, cats, birds, fish, and then some).

I'm a grammar nazi, and will edit out any spelling or grammatical errors I find. I have experience with community building, topic selection, organizing site events, and more.

Whatever the choice, is, I'll welcome any decision the community makes as a whole, because that's the whole point :)